# Use NLTK or similar tool to tell sentence boundary

Tags: nltk

I know how to split sentence with NLTK PunktSentenceTokenizer.

However I have another request: I have a text converted from pdf where the page break splits sentences. Is there any way of using NLTK to tell whether a string end is a sentence boundary or not? if it is not sentence boundary, I can concatenate the string with next string.

For example, here are my strings:

"I have a text converted"
"Is there any way to save human kind?"

The first one is not a sentence end and the second is.

Comment: However, I come out an idea now, maybe clumsy. I'll firstly concatenate current string with next one, with string length saved. Then I use NLTK sentence tokenizer to split the new string. Then I can check whether the previous string boundary is divided by NLTK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with English, `nltk` already provided an API for you: `english.pickle`.

```py
import nltk.data
text = '''
(How does it deal with this parenthesis?)  "It should be part of the
previous sentence." "(And the same with this one.)" ('And this one!')
"('(And (this)) '?)" [(and this. )]
'''
sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
print('\n-----\n'.join(sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip())))
```

Output:

```py
(How does it deal with this parenthesis?)
-----
"It should be part of the
previous sentence."
-----
"(And the same with this one.)"
-----
('And this one!')
-----
"('(And (this)) '?)"
-----
[(and this. )]
```

Read more in [nltk.tokenize](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html)

Comment: Sorry I don't get you. I know i can call NLTK tokenizer to split a long string into sentences. I have updated my question with examples.

Comment: @DavidPeng, My answer is suggesting for you to get a sentence even 2-3 parts of a sentence are not in 1 line. What is your SENTENCE definition? End with punctuation?